# How can I remap an ActiveRecord attribute into a foreign key with a minimum of disruption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model that I'm building in my Rails app for a product's Price:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :country_code, :product, :amount
  validates_uniqueness_of :product, :scope => [:country_code]
end
```

Appropriately, the DB model is as follows:

```
create_table :prices do |t|
  t.string :country_code
  t.integer :product_id
  t.integer :amount
end
```

The complication is that, at the moment, Product isn't an actual ActiveRecord model -- it's a Struct wrapped around a single ID attribute (item_code) with a lot of constants and helper methods. There are plans in a future sprint to refactor it back into the database properly, but right now, much of our app code uses Product as if it's coming from the DB already, and ideally, I'd like to isolate as many changes for once Product becomes a proper table to just the models that would have direct relationships in the DB.

The question, then, is to cleanly handle the foreign key relationship in the model when there is no actual other table in the underlying DB. To get around it logically, I've added the following validation to Price:

```
validates_inclusion_of :product, :in => Product.all
```

Where Product.all is a method that simulates these objects coming from a table without being an actual ActiveRecord class.

All this together leads to the issue that, as far as I understand it, because there's no Product table, ActiveRecord isn't creating :product accessors (and is instead using :product_id directly). However, if I rely on :product_id, I've made it harder to migrate once Product becomes an actual ActiveRecord class.

Is there a simple way to 'alias' the :product attribute to the :product_id field so that the code is isolated within the Product (or even the Price model) in such a way that, for all intents and purposes, :product is automatically mapped as if there was a relationship in the database tables? The ideal solution, obviously, would be some method or alias instruction that could just be removed at some future date, and suddenly everything would act as though product_id has always pointed to the products table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to fake the fields as if you had a `has_one` relationship setup in the Price model, you can just define the methods yourself in your Price model. As you didn't give an example of how you select from the Product Struct, the below is a code example if you were trying to re-implement it for an ActiveModel.

```
def product
    if self.product_id
        if !@product or @product.id != self.product_id
            @product = Product.find(self.product_id)
        else
            @product
        end
    end
end

def product=(product)
    @product = product
    self.product_id = product._id
end
```

This will duplicate a `has_one` relationship where you can change it by setting it through `product` or `product_id` and it will only lookup a product once, and then again if it changes.

Comment: This did work, but I also had to do a few more things. Namely, the validates_uniqueness_of call had to be changed from :product to :product_id, and the ActiveRecord find calls had to use product_id instead of product (e.g. find_by_product_id_and_country_code). Other than that, this was the key I needed.